# C++ vectors - acessing the size of vector of type struct declared within a struct

Tags: c++, vector

My declaration is as follows

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct _ListofHops_T
{
  int macAddrLtr;
  int ttlValue;
}ListofHops;


struct ReadActivateLinkTrace
{
   typedef std::vector < ListofHops *> ListofHopsList;
   bool operationState;
};


int main()
{
    ReadActivateLinkTrace readLinkTrace;

    for (size_t listItr=0; listItr < readLinkTrace.ListofHopsList.size(); listItr++)
    {
      .....
    }
}
```

I am trying to declare a vector of list of hops `struct` within a struct `ReadActivateLinkTrace`.

1. Is the above declaration valid.
2. I get the following error compiling

> vector.cpp:23: error: invalid use of
>   ReadActivateLinkTrace::ListofHopsList

I am new to vectors . how can i acess/iterate through vector of structures defined in a structure?

Answer (score 1):

The declaration is valid, but it doesn't do what you think. `ListofHopsList` is a type (hint: `typedef`), not a variable. You're probably looking for

```
struct ReadActivateLinkTrace
{
   std::vector < ListofHops *> ListofHopsList;
   bool operationState;
};
```

The problem wasn't with the vector itself, but with the fact that you weren't declaring a member, but defining a new type.

Also, is there any reason you're using a vector of pointers as opposed to a vector of objects?

Answer (score 1):

ReadActivateLinkTrace::ListofHopsList is a `typedef`, which only declares an alias for a name of a type. It does not define an actual object of that type. You apparently want:

```
struct ReadActivateLinkTrace
{
   std::vector < ListofHops *> ListofHopsList;
   bool operationState;
};
```

You should *probably* have some second thoughts about that being a vector of pointers though. At least offhand, it doesn't seem very likely that a pointer is the best choice here. While you're at it, this:

```
typedef struct _ListofHops_T
{
  int macAddrLtr;
  int ttlValue;
}ListofHops;
```

Is pretty horrible in a couple of ways. First the `typedef` here is only needed in C code, not C++. Second, the name `_ListofHops_T` is reserved for the implementation, so using it gives undefined behavior. This should be just:

```
struct ListofHops { 
   int macAddrLtr;
   int ttlValue;
};
```